# Select Distinct Values for 2 colums but Not the 3rd

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL database and i want to select distinct City and StateInitials  + Zipcode of the selected City & State

I do not want to distinct all fields because then i will get 10+ for all major citys

here is what i have for Distinct City, StateInitials

```
$rs = mysql_query('select Distinct StateInitials, City from locations where City like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" limit 0,15', $dblink);
```

I want something like => Springfield, Mo, 65801

but dont want it to list => Springfield, Mo, 65802
                            Springfield, Mo, 65803

Comment: I could not understand your question. Could you please show some sample data and an example of the result you're trying to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use GROUP BY instead

```
   $term =mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']); 
   $rs = mysql_query("
                      select StateInitials, City 
                      from locations 
                      where City like '$term%' 
                      GROUP BY StateInitials, City
                      limit 0,15", $dblink);
```

Idont know why you say the third , while your query is only 2 columns :).

Comment: I want to Add a third i have tried but it was distint values of ZIPS as well